# Handle click and drag movement to scroll horizontally with mootools or jquery

Tags: jquery, mootools, click, scroll, drag

Is there an easy way to handle the movement event composed of click and drag to the left or to the right on a div, in order to do a classic slider.
The idea is to do something similar to the scrolling of iphone apps but with left mouse click.

Comment: thanks for de editing @Nicolás

Answer (score 21):

You mean something kind of like this?

```
var x,y,top,left,down;

$("#stuff").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    down = true;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    top = $(this).scrollTop();
    left = $(this).scrollLeft();
});

$("body").mousemove(function(e){
    if(down){
        var newX = e.pageX;
        var newY = e.pageY;

        $("#stuff").scrollTop(top - newY + y);    
        $("#stuff").scrollLeft(left - newX + x);    
    }
});

$("body").mouseup(function(e){down = false;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AhC87/2/

Click inside the area and drag to move around the div.  It's quick and dirty, but if that was what you were meaning, it's a good starting point.  Unless there's an existing plugin somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

ES6 version/Vanilla JS of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839943/145122

```
let el = document.querySelector("#yourhtmlelement");
let x = 0, y = 0, top = 0, left = 0;

let draggingFunction = (e) => {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", draggingFunction);
    });

    el.scrollLeft = left - e.pageX + x;
    el.scrollTop = top - e.pageY + y;
};

el.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    y = e.pageY;
    x = e.pageX;
    top = el.scrollTop;
    left = el.scrollLeft;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', draggingFunction);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi friend check this out I think this will solve your problem http://www.axure.com/forum/support-axure-com-collection/4418-answered-how-make-scrolling-page-scrollable-content-scroll-dynamic-panel-dragging-scrollbars-vertical-horizontal-drag-ondrag.html and this also http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Scroll 
 I think this will help you very much http://dragon.deparadox.com/